# Extracting data using JSoup

Tags: android, jsoup

I am trying to extract product name information from Google Shopping (http://www.google.co.uk/m/products?q=5010459007289, phone website).

The product name always appear in between the span with class "owb63p",for example

```
"<span class="owb63p">Highland Spring Sports Bottle 750 Ml</span>"
```

I am new with JSoup, I can connect with the URL and get the whole document, but I just need help setting it up so that I only get the piece of information I need.

Comment: I have managed to select the whole "span" line, by using:      Element masthead = doc.select("span.owb63p").first(); then just splitted the string to get the product name. is this the correct way?

Answer (score 1):

In JSoup it will be like:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("www.google.co.uk/m/products?q=5010459007289").get();
Element title = doc.select("span.owb63p").first();
    System.out.println(title.text());
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't like JSoup that much, but with apache [jericho](http://jericho.htmlparser.net/) it would like :

```
            Source source=new Source(new URL(sourceUrlString));
    String content=source.getFirstElementByClass( "owb63p" ).getContent().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [JSoup examples](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/attributes-text-html) has what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
doc.select("span").get(0).data();
```

or you can simply iterate for multiple span tags...